# How to pass data from identical multiple child component to parent in angular?

Tags: angular, parent-child

I would like to pass data from multiple identical child components to parent component. How can I achieve it. Scenario is I have a date picker and I looped the child components in parent component. So when I select date in all the child elements how can I retrieve the dates in parent component where I am having my business logic to make a service call. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a service and then provided it in the parent component using an injection token. Then inject the token into the child components, they can then access the parent.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn can you please share working code if you have or a sample

Comment: You should use @Output() in your child component and send values to the parent component when the date is selected.

Comment: @DeveshShukla you have any sample with identical childs for the same

Comment: There are literally 50 patterns that could achieve this with different pros and cons. Sample code and details on what you’re trying to do will let people guide you to the best solution.

Comment: @bryan60 my use case is I have a parent component and I iterate the date picker like say two times. Once I select dates in each child. I should be able to know which date picker selected which date in parent component and then use it in the service call to create an object. Is it clear now ? Please help

Comment: post code showing what you have tried

Comment: @bryan60 I yet to work on it, will post it asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep an array for all the children and their respective values in the parent component. Whenever the date value is changed in the child component, use an event emitter to pass that value to the parent. See the example below:

Child.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss'],
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() data: any;
  @Output('selectionChanged') eventEmitter: EventEmitter<any> =
    new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor() {}

  onDateSelection(event: any) {
    const dateStr = event.target.value; //Pick date value
    this.eventEmitter.emit({ id: this.data.id, date: dateStr });
  }
}
```

Child.component.html

```
<p>id: {{ data.id }}</p>
<input type="date" (change)="onDateSelection($event)" />
```

App.component.ts (In your case this will be parent component)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'so-demo';
  children: any[];
  constructor() {
    this.children = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
  }
  ngOnInit() {}

  dateSelectionChanged(data: any) {
    const { id, date } = data;
    this.children[id - 1].date = date;
    // Call your service here, I'm just gonna write to console
    console.log(this.children);
  }
}
```

App.component.html

```
<p>Hola! Select a few of below dates:</p>
<ng-container *ngFor="let c of children">
  <app-child
    [data]="c"
    (selectionChanged)="dateSelectionChanged($event)"
  ></app-child>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks Devesh will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

You can talk to a parent component by creating a provider that references the current component. Any child will then have access to that parent. See the full code on [Stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m2j1o8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts).

First step is to create a token that can be provided to your parent and injected into your children:

```js
export const PARENT_COMPONENT = new InjectionToken<ParentComponent>('ParentToken');
```

Next in your parent component add a provider that references itself:

```js
@Component({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: PARENT_COMPONENT,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ParentComponent),
    },
  ],
})
export class ParentComponent {}
```

Then in your children, inject the parent:

```js
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(
    @Inject(PARENT_COMPONENT) private readonly parent: ParentComponent
  ) {}
}
```

Now the child has access to all the parents functions, and it doesn't matter how deep the child is within the component, it could be a child or even a grand grand child (or deeper).

Comment: What is the advantage of this vs a service?

Comment: You have direct access to the component. No middle man. However I am not opposed to a service either.

Comment: Also makes the event system simpler. With the service you would have to send a message to the service which then would send a message to the event which then the component would be listening to. With this it is a direct message to the component.

Comment: to each their own, but I'd not recommend this approach of injecting a parent and calling it's functions directly. IMO it complicates the event system as it creates a system where there's a strong hidden dependency between child and parent and a system that could be difficult for new devs (or old devs changing old code) to figure out when things are happening and why. 

I'm also not sure the benefit of the injection tokens here.